# Error summary not shown in CActiveForm - Yii

Tags: php, yii

Below i am using `CActiveForm` to render a form with multiple instances of same model. On submitting the form, ajax validation error for individual attributes are shown but `error summary` is not shown. What could be the possible problem? Thanks a lot

```
<?php 
    $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'task-form',
        'enableClientValidation'=>false,
        'enableAjaxValidation' =>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array(
            'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
            'validateOnChange'=>false,
        ),
    )); 
    Yii::app()->session['form'] = $form;
    ?>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($models); ?> 

    <ul class="tasks">
        <?php foreach($models as $index=>$model): ?>
            <?php $this->renderPartial('_task', array(
                'model' => $model,
                'index' => $index,
                'form' => $form,
            )); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Save')?>
    </div>

    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well an extreme case of CActiveForm. Why you ever need this many Forms as in array. You can use them in single Form. But the problem is again due to multiple instance of form. Here

```
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($models); ?>
```

Use it just like this-

```
 foreach($models as $model)
 {
 echo $form->errorSummary($model);
 }
```

But again you need to change implementation and avoid using that many duplicate forms.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
```

or try to use

```
 <?php echo CHtml::errorSummary(array($a,$b)); ?>
```